# Elementwise multiplication of NumPy arrays of different shapes

Tags: numpy, matrix, vector, linear-algebra, multiplication

When I use `numpy.multiply(a,b)` to multiply numpy arrays with shapes `(2, 1),(2,)` I get a 2 by 2 matrix. But what I want is element-wise multiplication.

I'm not familiar with numpy's rules. Can anyone explain what's happening here?

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html ?

Comment: @JonClements I read through it but couldn't understand it very well (the are all something like 1*2*3 but in my case I've got 2*0). Can you give some explanation?

Answer (score 3):

When doing an element-wise operation between two arrays, which are *not* of the same dimensionality, NumPy will perform broadcasting. In your case Numpy will broadcast `b` along the rows of `a`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1],
              [2]])
b = [3, 4]
print(a * b)
```

Gives:

```
[[3 4]
 [6 8]]
```

To prevent this, you need to make `a` and `b` of the same dimensionality. You can add dimensions to an array by using `np.newaxis` or `None` in your indexing, like this:

```
print(a * b[:, np.newaxis])
```

Gives:

```
[[3]
 [8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have two arrays, `a` and `b`, with shape `(2,3)` and `(2,)` respectively:

```
a = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,3))
b = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,))
```

The two arrays, for example, contain:

```
a = np.array([[8, 0, 3],
              [2, 6, 7]])
b = np.array([7, 5])
```

Now for handling a product element to element `a*b` you have to specify what numpy has to do when reaching for the absent `axis=1` of array `b`. You can do so by adding `None`:

```
result = a*b[:,None]
```

With `result` being:

```
array([[56,  0, 21],
       [10, 30, 35]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the input arrays `a` and `b` of the same shape as you mentioned:

```
In [136]: a
Out[136]: 
array([[0],
       [1]])

In [137]: b
Out[137]: array([0, 1])
```

Now, when we do multiplication using either `*` or `numpy.multiply(a, b)`, we get:

```
In [138]: a * b
Out[138]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

The result is a `(2,2)` array because numpy uses broadcasting.

```
       # b
    #a | 0     1
     ------------
     0 | 0*0   0*1
     1 | 1*0   1*1
```

Answer (score 1):

If a and b are Python lists. The following code works.

```py
import numpy as np
def multiply_elementwise_arrays(a, b):
        a = np.array(a)
        b = np.array(b)        
        if a.size == b.size:
            return a*b
        elif a.size < b.size:
            a = np.array(a[:,None])
            return b*a
        else:
            b = np.array(b[:,None])
            return a*b
```

Answer (score 0):

I just explained the broadcasting rules in [broadcasting arrays in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349661/broadcasting-arrays-in-numpy/51349925#51349925)

In your case

```
(2,1) + (2,) => (2,1) + (1,2) => (2,2)
```

It has to add a dimension to the 2nd argument, and can only add it at the beginning (to avoid ambiguity).

So you want a (2,1) result, you have to expand the 2nd argument yourself, with `reshape` or `[:, np.newaxis]`.