# broadcasting arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I got an array and reshaped it to the following dimentions: (-1,1,1,1) and (-1,1):

```
 Array A:
[-0.888788523827  0.11842529285   0.319928774626  0.319928774626  0.378755429421  1.225877519716  3.830653798838]

A.reshape(-1,1,1,1):
[[[[-0.888788523827]]]


 [[[ 0.11842529285 ]]]


 [[[ 0.319928774626]]]


 [[[ 0.319928774626]]]


 [[[ 0.378755429421]]]


 [[[ 1.225877519716]]]


 [[[ 3.830653798838]]]]

A.reshape(-1,1):
[[-0.888788523827]
 [ 0.11842529285 ]
 [ 0.319928774626]
 [ 0.319928774626]
 [ 0.378755429421]
 [ 1.225877519716]
 [ 3.830653798838]]
```

Then I have done substractig and broadcasting came in, so my resulting matrix is 7x1x7x1.

I have a hard time to visualize the intermediate step what broadcasting does. I mean I cannot imagine what elements of arrays are repeated and what they look like while broadcasting. 
Could somebody shed some light on this problem,please?

Comment: It's hard wrap your head around with such unwieldy shaped arrays. Take a small example and try to understand from that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [5]: arr = np.arange(4)
In [6]: A = arr.reshape(-1,1,1,1)
In [7]: B = arr.reshape(-1,1)
In [8]: C = A + B
In [9]: C.shape
Out[9]: (4, 1, 4, 1)
In [10]: A.shape
Out[10]: (4, 1, 1, 1)
In [11]: B.shape
Out[11]: (4, 1)
```

There are 2 basic broadcasting rules:

- expand the dimensions to match - by adding size 1 dimensions at the start
- adjust all size 1 dimensions to match

So in this example:

```
 (4,1,1,1) + (4,1)
 (4,1,1,1) + (1,1,4,1)    # add 2 size 1's to B
 (4,1,4,1) + (4,1,4,1)    # adjust 2 of the 1's to 4
 (4,1,4,1)
```

The first step is, perhaps, the most confusing.  The (4,1) is expanded to (1,1,4,1), not (4,1,1,1).  The rule is intended to avoid ambiguity - by expanding in a consistent manner, not necessarily what a human might intuitively want.

Imagine the case where both arrays need expansion to match, and it could add a dimension in either direction:

```
 (4,) and (3,)
 (1,4) and (3,1)  or (4,1) and (1,3)
 (3,4)            or (4,3)
 confusion
```

The rule requires that the programmer choose which one expands to the right (4,1) or (3,1).  `numpy` can then unambiguously add the other.

---

For a simpler example:

```
In [22]: A=np.arange(3).reshape(-1,1)
In [23]: B=np.arange(3)
In [24]: C = A+B   (3,1)+(3,) => (3,1)+(1,3) => (3,3)
In [25]: C
Out[25]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
In [26]: C.shape
Out[26]: (3, 3)
```

The [0,2,4] are present, but on the diagonal of `C`.

When broadcasting like this, the result is a kind of `outer` sum:

```
In [27]: np.add.outer(B,B)
Out[27]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I got this point. Though I do not understand how columns and rows are stretched. I took a simpler example. arr = np.arange(3), A = arr.reshape(-1,1,1), B=arr.reshape(-1,1), and the resulting C is different then I expected. I thought it should have been an array with elements 0,2,4, but I was mistaken.

Comment: I added a simpler example.